# jedi-vim autocompletion. complete by grep-style searching

Tags: jedi-vim

I'm comparing PyCharm autocomplete search and jedi-vim in Vim.

In PyCharm I'm able to see the list of methods. where the search pattern might in the beginning/middle/end.

In VIM I can only see methods, which starting at the beginning of the search pattern.

I wonder if it's my configuration or it's as expected?  If not what suggestion can you propose.  Thanks.

PyCharm example:
[image]

Vim example:
[image]

Ivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently not a feature of jedi-vim to search for strings in names (not that this would be hard, but it's not a Jedi feature).

If you really want this, please try out YouCompleteMe. It also uses Jedi and has support for generic substring searching.

Comment: Dave, thanks for the answer and for jedi-vim! It's clear now.